# Three related tables - How to deal

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**House** (id, name)

**People** (id, name)

**Phone** (id, number)

Idea: A house has MANY people and each person may have MANY numbers.

**Relationship table:**

**house_has_people_has_phone** (id, house_id, people_id, phone_id)

So, I want to build this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
   (
     [id] 1
     [name] House 01
     [people] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
         (
           [id] 1
           [name] John
           [phone] => Array
            (
              [0] => Array
               (
                 [id] 1
                 [number] 555
               )
              [1] => Array
               (
                 [id] 2
                 [number] 777
               )
            )
          )
         [1] => Array
          (
            [id] 2
            [name] Mick
            [phone] => Array
             (
               [0] => Array
                (
                  [id] 3
                  [number] 999
                )
             )
          )
       )
    )
)
```

And finally, how can I relate it in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

There is really no relationship of a `Phone` to a `House` so you don't want to do the 3-level relationship you are considering.  Don't worry, Laravel will let you retrieve the data structure you want when the time comes (see below) but the final data result is not how you should model it.

You need to consider the reverse relationship too... I am assuming that a `People` can only belong to one `House` and likewise a `Phone` can only belong to one `People`.

In Laravel `/models`

House.php

```
class House extends Eloquent {
    public function people() {
        return $this->hasMany('People');
    }
}
```

People.php

```
class People extends Eloquent {
    public function house() {
        return $this->belongsTo('House');
    }

    public function phone {
        return $this->hasMany('Phone');
    }
}
```

Phone.php

```
class Phone extends Eloquent {
    public function people() {
        return $this->belongsTo('People');
    }
}
```

Models tend to be singlular so you might want to rename `People` to `Person`.